# how to issue query for multi layers linked tables in symfony

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, foreign-keys, left-join

I have a question about how to issue the createQueryBuilder for multilayers linked tables.

I have one table "City" with a column "country_id" linked to a table "Country". The "Country" table has a column "zone_id" linked to table "Zone".

How can I generate the QueryBuilder for the SQL as follow?

```
Select * from City
LEFT JOIN Country AS c ON City.country_id=c.id
LEFT JOIN Zone AS z ON c.zone_id=z.id
WHERE z.id In (1,2,3,4)
```

In my city entity and country entity, I have made the ManytoOne link relationships.

In CityEntity.php

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
 private $country;
```

In CountryEntity.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Zone",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $zone;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, or something very close to it. I can't syntax check it right now.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$results = $qb->select('c, co, z')
    ->from('AppBundle:City', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.country', 'co')
    ->leftJoin('co.zone', 'z', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->in('z.id', [1,2,3,4]))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Note this will return countries with zones that are not in the zone id array. If your intent is to restrict by zone, you should be using join not leftJoin. In which case the query would look something like this:

```
    $results = $qb->select('c, co, z')
        ->from('AppBundle:City', 'c')
        ->join('c.country', 'co')
        ->join('co.zone', 'z')
        ->where($qb->expr()->in('z.id', [1,2,3,4]))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks. That works.
I still have a question about this issue.
I tried to use the code as follows to avoid use "join". But it doesn't work.

`$results->andWhere("c.country.zone IN [1,2,3,4]")`

But if I use the same method to treat the country. It works, such as.

`$results->andWhere("c.country IN [1,2,3,4]")`

Do you know if it's possible to use the style `obj1.obj2.obj3` ?

Comment: You definitely need to join, and you can't use obj1.obj2.obj3. I would guess when you use c.country it is just restricting on country id, not zone id. Nothing wrong with joining, if it's slow and you have a large dataset, look at your indexes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard.